# Talmud source that the righteous can create worlds with their words

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, creation, tzaddikim

Looking for a source in the talmud which says that the righteous can create worlds with their words - I saw this and I can't remember in which tractate/where exactly, google isn't helping.

Comment: Nati, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! I hope you get excellent answers to this question, and I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: מעבר לכך כתוב מה ה'' בורא עולמות אף הצדיקים בוראים עולמות, כמאמר המדרש על הפסוק: ושמעו אל ישראל אביכם (בראשית מט ב): א-ל הוא ישראל אביכם, מה הקב"ה בונה עולמות אף אביכם בונה עולמות, מה הקב"ה מחלק עולמות, אף אביכם מחלק עולמות (בראשית רבה פמ"ט).
http://www.kaduri.net/?CategoryID=131&ArticleID=52701

Comment: The early Hassidic figure Rabbi Dov Ber of Lemberg, a disciple of the Baal Shem Tov writes this (as recorded in Torat HaMagid (Tehillim)): 
צדיק מושל יראת אלהים, וצדיקים בוראים עולמות ומחיים מתים ופוקדים עקרות "The righteous create worlds and resuscitate the dead"